# How to show the popup message when user tries to install on Unsupported Operating System

Tags: nsis

When installing the software, I wanted to detect the operating system and if it is "Windows 10 Pro" or "Windows Server 2012" it should pop up a message box and the installation should stop.

**I am using the below code snippet.** But here even if the operating system is "Windows 10 Pro", message box is not popping up.

```
ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" "ProductName"

${If} $R0 == "Windows 10 Pro"

MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONQUESTION "This operating system is not supported." IDOK
 Quit
${EndIf}
```

Is it the correct way or is there any way we can detect the operating system and show the message box?

Comment: Why? Also, Server 2012 is way older than Windows 10 so your requirement does not really make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand why you need these restrictions but here you go:

```
!include WinVer.nsh

!define /IfNDef PRODUCT_PROFESSIONAL      0x00000030
!define /IfNDef PRODUCT_PROFESSIONAL_N    0x00000031
!define /IfNDef PRODUCT_PRO_WORKSTATION   0x000000A1
!define /IfNDef PRODUCT_PRO_WORKSTATION_N 0x000000A2
!define /IfNDef ERROR_INSTALL_REJECTED 1654

Function .onInit
System::Call 'KERNEL32::GetProductInfo(i6,i1,i0,i0,*i0r1)'
${WinVerGetBuild} $2

${If} ${IsServerOS} ; Windows Server?
${AndIf} $2 U>= 9200 ; Server 2012?
${AndIf} $2 U<  9600 ; and not Server 2012 R2?
    Goto die_unsupported_os
${EndIf}

${If} $2 U>= 9800 ; Windows 10?
${AndIfNot} ${IsServerOS} ; Not Windows Server?
    ${If} $1 = ${PRODUCT_PROFESSIONAL}
    ${OrIf} $1 = ${PRODUCT_PROFESSIONAL_N}
    ${OrIf} $1 = ${PRODUCT_PRO_WORKSTATION}
    ${OrIf} $1 = ${PRODUCT_PRO_WORKSTATION_N}
        die_unsupported_os:
        MessageBox mb_IconStop|mb_OK "Not allowed to run on this version of Windows for some reason!" /SD IDOK
        SetErrorLevel ${ERROR_INSTALL_REJECTED}
        Quit
    ${EndIf}
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Note: Windows Insider builds are also identified as Pro so you will end up blocking those as well.